# Developing a "Flash Briefing" on Google Home

Tags: actions-on-google, google-home

I publish a flash briefing skill on Amazon's Alexa. It is a brief news update on a specific topic. I provide the information to Alexa via a json file that is updated every 10 minutes.

I'd like to publish something similar on Google Home devices. However, when I look at DialogFlow, that API appears to be conversational-based. Is that the right API for this type of app? Is there a Template for flash-briefing-like apps (i.e., easy to launch apps that don't require any additional user input after launching)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't need a conversational Action for what you're doing.

Depending on the specifics of how you're providing the content, you may wish to look at either [Podcast Actions](https://developers.google.com/actions/content-actions/podcasts) or [News Actions](https://developers.google.com/actions/content-actions/news). These methods document what Google is looking for to make structured content available to the Google Assistant.